# EcoreUtil.equals returns false when comparing 2 EObjects created by loading the same resource from different locations

Tags: eclipse-emf-ecore

I am observing a weird behavior with `EcoreUtil.equals` method. I am loading 2 XML files which are exactly the same from 2 different locations (I have the same file at 2 locations) using Resource's `createResource` and `load` methods.

`ECoreUtil.equals` returns false for these 2 `EObjects`. When I debug the `EcoreUtil.equals` code, I see that it fails because of the == check on `EClass` and `EStructuralFeature`. Note that the classes and structural features are the same, however, 2 separate instances of `EClass` and `EStructuralFeature` are seen. `EcoreUtil.equals` does a == check on feature and class and therefore fails.

What I am unable to understand is why would there be 2 instances created for `EClass` and `EStructuralFeature`. I am sure there is no difference in the 2 XML files. One is a copy of the other.

Is there any setting in the ecore model that could be the reason? My XML files have `xmi:id` attribute in them.

I am stumped by this behavior. Can anyone give any pointers?

Regards,
Arati

Answer (score 1):

It's better to ask about EMF on the eclipse.tools.emf forum.

There's nothing in your question that gives a hint on why there would be more than one EPackage.  It seems to suggest you have an instance file that uses a dynamic Ecore model. Is that the case?  Even in this case, if you load the resources in the same resource set, they should end up sharing a single model.

Comment: Hi Ed - Thanks for the reply. I have posted on eclipse forum, but that is moderated list. I tried loading the resource using the same resource set, but did not help. Actually, the XML snippet is getting mapped to AnyTypeImpl (since my XML file can contain different types of objects that I cannot control, it is extensible). So I do not have the EPackage to URI mapping available for it. As a result, I end up comparing two AnyTypeImpl EObjects, which internally have FeatureMaps. And I always get 2 different instances of the EClass or the FeatureMap or the EStructuralFeature.